# Input values in an array using do-while loop using php

Tags: php

```
 do {
$pet_name = $row['pet_called'];

$ary = array($pet_name);

}while($row_pet = mysql_fetch_assoc($pet));
```

When called it must display the value, which can be done by the for loop etc.

```
echo $ary[0..x];
```

This is not working and how do i get to do this?

Comment: Sorry.. I'm not following the question.

Comment: What trouble are you having?  You have the right idea.

Comment: @Brad Its just not working out

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, do you know?

Comment: @X10nD, It's just not working out?  I don't know what you expect us to infer from that.  What is the problem.

Comment: Why do you use `do ... while` and not a simple `while`? In the first iteration `$row` will not be set to a value with this code.

Comment: @Brad Okay, I need to insert values into the array from the db using a do-while and when called as @ary[7] it should read the value.

Comment: @ChrisCooney What part are you not following?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ary = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pet)) { 
    $ary[] = $row['pet_called'];
}
```

`$ary[] = ...` is the syntax to add an element to an array.

Comment: Where were you hiding all this time.. exactly what I wanted.. Thanks../

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `do...while`. Nothing will be set to `$row` in the first iteration. This is why it doesn't work. Try just `while`:

```
$ary = array();
while($row_pet = mysql_fetch_assoc($pet))
{
$ary[] = $row_pet['pet_called'];
}
```

Comment: I get only $pet_name[0] which is the last output.  Nothing beyond $pet_name[0];